# How to know an address balance X number of days ago?

Tags: solidity, bsc, binance-smart-chain

Im creating a new contract at the moment. With one of the features im trying to implement i need to know what the senders address balance was 28 days ago.

My current idea is to store an mapping of all changes to the balance including the timestamp. When i need to find the balance i will iterate through the mapping until i find the appropriate balance with a timestamp less than or equal to 28 days ago.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getBalance` method of [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.1/web3-eth.html?highlight=getbalance#getbalance) or [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getBalance) by providing the last block's number mined 28 days ago as a parameter. Example code for ethers.js:

```
const currentBlock = await provider.getBlockNumber();
// A rough estimation of the average block time in seconds
const blockTime = 15;
const hoursIn28Days = 28 * 24;
const blockNumber28DaysAgo= currentBlock - (hoursIn28Days * 60 * 60) / blockTime;
const address = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

const balance28DaysAgo = await provider.getBalance(address, blockNumber28DaysAgo);
```